# Dynamic query using parameters in Tableau

Tags: sql, postgresql, tableau-api, bigdata

I am trying to utilize tableau in creating a web dashboard to interact with a postgres database with a fair amount of rows.

The key here is the relevant data is within latitude/longitude boundaries, so I'm using tableau parameters in a custom SQL statement to get what I need, like so

```
SELECT id, lat, lng... FROM my_table
WHERE lat >= <Parameters.MIN_LAT> AND lat <= <Parameters.MAX_LAT>
AND lng >= <Parameters.MIN_LNG> AND lng <= <Parameters.MAX_LNG>
LIMIT 10000
```

I'm setting these parameters using the Tableau JavaScript API based off of a Google maps widget boundaries. When the map is moved, I'll refresh the parameters and the data needs to update as well. This refresh is not done constantly, but frequent enough that long wait times are not acceptable.

Because the lat/lng boundaries are dynamic and the full unfiltered table is very big (~1GB) I presumed it is impractical to create a data extract. Am I wrong?

Furthermore when I change some of the in-Tableau filters I'm applying there is a very long wait as if it is re-executing the query every-time, even if the MIN_LAT, MAX_LAT, .. parameters are un-changed.

What's the best way of resolving this? I'm new to Tableau so sorry if I'm missing something super obvious!

Thanks.

Comment: I would start by giving an extract a shot, this will improve your performance on Tableau desktop and help with your filter delay issues. If you're not using an extract then the query will run with every interaction.

Comment: You don't need custom SQL for this. Regular filters will work fine and better allow Tableau to generate efficient SQL

Answer (score 0):

**The best way of resolving this**, is by making a query with less information on it (1GB is too much, the extract can help to group data to present dimensions very fast, but that's it.. if there is nothing to group it will be very extense), which permits doing a drill down to present more information on subsequents steps or dashboards levels.
I am thinking of a field of the database which can tell the zoom level of presenting information.
If you are navigating on googlemaps... first you find the countrys, then the capital cities, then the cities, then the small towns, then the local stores...

The key is on the zoom level you are on each time.

[You may visit Tableau about Drill downs.](https://community.tableau.com/thread/153220)